# simple way to detect street area in google map images (aerial images)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

im trying to detect the area of the street in image without any deep learning method.

say i have this image:

[image]

i am looking for any simple method to detect street portion of the image like the following:

[image]

now i know this might not be very accurate, and accuracy is not the problem at all , i am trying to achieve this without using any deep learning method.

Comment: Did you try edge detection and [Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)?

Comment: @PayamBeirami Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62623836/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Hough line can give direct straight line measure. but i don't thin it will give you exactly what you want. As shown below

[image]

You need a lot more complicated algorithms such as deep sematic segmentation model. and train based on that.

Even you don't like  deep learning. traditional algo such as variational analysis, SVM learning or adaboost is also very complicated and you wont be able to use it easily. You need to have mucher deeper understanding on those topic.

if you really want you can start with variational analysis, active contour model, snake energy for extracting the  road first.  This variational analysis is proven to be working for a complex scenes and extract a particular model as shown in the image below.  your road is the empty low gradient region and all building tree nearby are high gradient responses that you don't want.

[image]

My suggestion is to make your life easier by using pre trained model and extra the surface model.  Download, run python script. that's all

There are a few open-source implementations that you can try such as this

https://github.com/ArkaJU/U-Net-Satellite

https://github.com/Paulymorphous/Road-Segmentation

https://github.com/avanetten/cresi

[image]

Based on the predicted mask. then you can get production accurately as shown below

[image]

This would be the result that you are looking for

Regards

Shenghai Yuan

Comment: Thanks , but non of the repos seem to work , or i couldn't make them run

Comment: https://github.com/Paulymorphous/Road-Segmentation   this one does provide model, to required system installation to code to run. for there are dozens of work on this in github. you can search all for the package that is easy to build on your PC.   not sure what problem you have. if its the compatibility issue, you can always try with docker  or conda